# Regular expression for non-positive integer (ie negative integers and 0)

Tags: regex

Currently my solution is

```
/^-\d+$/
```

However, this solution excludes zero ie `0`.

How to update this so that it matches integers less or equal to 0?

Comment: What about `^(0|-\d+)$`

Comment: ah, you are right! just start to learn regex. don't know it can be simply solved in this way, Thank you!

Comment: All numeric parsers accept negative zero. If you're trying to beautify some text, you could match `^-0$` and replace with `0` Or if you expect 0 standalone `^(?:0+|-\d+)$`

Comment: @codingsnake99: in this case continue to learn regex taking the time to read at least a whole tutorial.

Comment: @RyszardCzech That will accept all positive numbers, not just 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude matching a number that starts with 1-9 preceded with optional zeroes.

```
^(?!0*[1-9])-?\d+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OMosoI/1)

Or with the alternation as in the comments to match 1+ times a zero, or only a single zero.

If supported, [you could use](https://regex101.com/r/WcR405/1) a possessive quantifier `0++` to prevent some backtracking.

```
^(?:0+|-\d+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E0YiKI/1)